# Mapping conflict Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

I am using EF codeFirst in order to create my database. 
I have 2 models Blog and Message with the below fields, I am getting a mapping conflict since Message table has a foreign key to the blog table and Also blog table has a foreign key with the lastMessage posted to the Message table.

```
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Topic{ get; set; }

        public virtual Message LastMessage{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Blog>
    {
        public BlogMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            HasKey(t => t.BlogId);

            // Properties
            Property(t => t.BlogId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            ToTable("Blog");
            Property(t => t.Topic).HasColumnName("Topic").HasMaxLength(100);

            // Relationships
            HasOptional(t => t.LastMessage)
                .WithRequired(t => t.Blog)
                .Map(t => t.MapKey("LastMessageId"));
        }
    }

public class MessageMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Message>
    {
        public MessageMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            HasKey(t => t.MessageId);

            // Properties
            Property(t => t.MessageId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            ToTable("Message");
            Property(t => t.Text).HasColumnName("Text").HasMaxLength(100);

            // Relationships
            HasRequired(t => t.Blog)
                .WithOptional()
                .Map(t => t.MapKey("BlogId"));
        }
    }
```

Exception:

{"The navigation property 'Blog' declared on type 'MyProject.DAL.Model.Message' has been configured with conflicting mapping information."}

Comment: How do you plan to maintain the proper data in the LastMessage property?

Comment: the relationship is confusing for me, is that one to one relationship? if so, which one is the principal? or probably what you need is just a simple one to many, one blog has many messages, blog doesn't have to have lastmessage, you can just manage it in the UI, `blog.Messages.OrderByDescending(..).FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the fix, I removed the navigation property on the other side of the relationship using WithMany()

Add BlogId and MessageId to Message and Blog tables

Blog Mapping:

```
HasOptional(t => t.LastMessage).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.MessageId);

// Relationships
HasOptional(t => t.LastMessage)
          .WithRequired(t => t.Blog)
          .Map(t => t.MapKey("LastMessageId"));
```

Message Mapping:

```
HasOptional(t => t.Blog).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.BlogId);

// Relationships
 HasRequired(t => t.Blog)
            .WithOptional()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("BlogId"));
```

Comment: I know this was answered two years ago but Im following this answer and in the Blog Mapping how does the blog model have the ability to reference itself on the line .WithRequired(t => t.Blog)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have mapped the "Blog" property of the Message class twice. In the BlogMap class, you define it here:

```
HasOptional(t => t.LastMessage)
                .WithRequired(t => t.Blog)
                .Map(t => t.MapKey("LastMessageId"));
```

This tells EF that the Blog property is the "return" side of the LastMessageId relationship.

In the MessageMap class, you define it here:

```
    HasRequired(t => t.Blog)
        .WithOptional()
        .Map(t => t.MapKey("BlogId"));
```

This says that the Blog property represents the BlogId relationship.

I suspect the second one is the one you actually want, and the WithRequired() line of the first relationship should be replaced with .WithOptional() like this:

```
   HasOptional(t => t.LastMessage)
                .WithOptional()
                .Map(t => t.MapKey("LastMessageId"));
```